# How to update a table based on the values in another table?

Tags: oracle, plsql, sql-update, correlated-subquery

I am trying to update a column in one table with the values contained in the column from another table.
I've tried the following but it gives me an error saying it returns more than one row.

```
update Table1 set description1 = (select description2 from Table2)
where customer_id in (select customer_id from Table2);
```

Any guidance?

Comment: Can you explain more what you're trying to do?  The reason is the first subselect, `(select descriptrion2 from Table2)`.

Comment: Basically what I'm trying to do is make the column description1 in Table1 equal to column description2 in Table2. Each row in both tables has a customer_id column that is identical.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To do a correlated update, your subquery has to return a single row.  Almost always, you do this by correlating the key that tells you which row from `table2` maps to which row from `table1`.  Assuming that both tables have a column named `key` that is unique

```
UPDATE table1 t1
   SET description = (SELECT t2.description2
                        FROM table2 t2
                       WHERE t1.key = t2.key)
 WHERE t1.customer_id IN (SELECT t2.customer_id
                            FROM table2)
```

Comment: I think the OP is trying to use customer_id as key but doing join incorrectly

Comment: @Nimesh - In which case `key` would be replaced by `customer_id` in the real query.  On the other hand, `customer_id` may just be part of the key and not the full key.

Answer (score 0):

It seems `select description2 from Table2` is returning more than one row.
Since Oracle does not know to which value(`description`) to update exactly.

Use a `WHERE CLAUSE` and Filter the rows to 1 if you want to update all values to same value(`description`).Check and run if the query `select description2 from Table2` returns only 1 row.

Else use keys for correlated update as suggested by Justin Cave.